# Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] gets IP6 instead IP4

Tags: asp.net, ip

Here is my code:

```
string ip = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

I use it for saving the `IP` for each login to a `UserLog` table.
Poorly it saves the `IP6` instead of the `IP4`.

What is the corret way?

Comment: Did you try to disable IPv6 on the server's network card?

Comment: Why the remote adress should something have to do with the server network card?

Comment: The network card is very relevant and its probably using IPv6, see my comment in my original answer.